# Batch script to return contrast text between two files

Tags: batch-file, diff

I need to write a batch file which can return the contrasted text between two csv files.
So for instance if 
`file1.csv` has:

```
"a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h"
```

and `file2.csv` has:

```
"a,b,c,d,e"
```

I need to return:

```
",f,g,h"
```

and save it to a new file.

I've tried using the COMP and DIFF (GNU DiffUtils) commands, but haven't been able to get the simple output format I need. I only need the contrasted data between the two files.
Does anyone know of a free tool I can use for this?

Many thanks,

-Will

Comment: The `xxdiff` program knows how to find out the changed characters between two files, but I can't figure out how to get it to just output _text_. Heh.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be enough for you?

```
cat file1.csv | cut -d, -f6-
```

(How would the content of file2.csv need to be of influence?)

e.g.

```
echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h"  | cut -d, -f6-
f,g,h
```

**Edit** additionally, there is http://os.ghalkes.nl/dwdiff.html This *will* result in quite different output formats though

Comment: The contents of file2 need to be compared to the contents of file1 so that a difference set of characters can be returned. In essence I need to return the set of characters which have been added to each subsequent file iteration.